# move object in unity -

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Yonti, I'm trying to build a simple maze game, and I'm trying to make the player's object move, but I'm not been able to do that for a few hours.

This is the code I wrote down:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PlayerMover : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed;

    public Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
    }
}
```

this is the player object:

[image]

I do not understand where I have a problem. I added the script to the player object and I get no error message. It just does not move, I do not understand why.I set "RigidBody" and gave speed to the object, I do not understand where there is an error.

Comment: @EhsanMohammadi thank you for the help, I'm new to that, can you explain it to more clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try turning off `isKinematic` on your rigidbody. The IsKinematic is used for animation/scripted moving with [`rb.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-position.html). In return, this will disable all forces on the rigidbody, causing your `rb.AddForce` to be ineffective.

> If isKinematic is enabled, Forces, collisions or joints will not affect the rigidbody anymore. ([This is taken from documenation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html))

I would also be cautious of the `Fixed Update`, [as it can loose Input signal with KeyDown and KeyUp;](https://forum.unity.com/threads/check-for-user-input-in-fixedupdate.214706/) but the way you are using it should be fine.

Comment: You should still never move a `Rigidbody` via `transform.position` but rather `rb.positiom` or `rb.MovePosition` to not break the collision detection ;) But yes this answer is right, `AddForce` doesn't work with is kinematic enabled

Answer (score 0):

Rigidbody probably interacts with terrain so; instead of using  "rigidbody"  you should use CharacterController  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html

Answer (score -1):

When you use **public variables** you always need to assign them in some ways because Unity will try to search from the `Inspector` firstly. You can simply fix your problem by setting the rigidbody to `private` and then assign it in the `Start()` like you were doing.

If you want to set the Rigidbody to be `public` you must assign it in the inspector by **dragging** the component of the rigidbody inside the inspector of the script

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I tried to do what you suggest, I made Rigidbody private - it still does not work for me. I do not understand why.